# Angular Typescript Share Properties Between Components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking to have some type of a config file that I can use to store properties that are needed in multiple components. Let me give you an example:

number-one-component.ts

```
export class NumberOneComponent {
    view: any[];
    xAxis: number;
    yAxis: number;
    label: string;
    labelPosition: string;

    chartSize: number;
}
```

number-two.component.ts

```
export class NumberTwoComponent {
    view: any[];
    xAxis: number;
    yAxis: number;
    label: string;
    labelPosition: string;

    chartSize: number;
}
```

I tried to create a file that I imported into one of the files and then do Object.assign(this, tokenName) in the constructor. Only problem was that TS complained about those properties not being part of the component.

I tried:

chart-config.ts

```
export const ChartConfig = {
    view: any[];
    xAxis: number;
    yAxis: number;
    label: string;
    labelPosition: string;

    chartSize: number;
}
```

That, did not work. In the constructor of either of the files, I did:

```
constructor() {
  Object.assign(this, ChartConfig);
}
```

With no luck.

I would appreciate insight as to how I can do this so that I can have a configuration file to share between components that need those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
export class NumberOneComponent {
    chartConfig = ChartConfig;
}

export class NumberTwoComponent {
    chartConfig = ChartConfig;
}
```

Then both components share the same config object.

in the template you would bind for example:

```
{{chartConfig.label}}
```

instead of

```
{{label}}
```

Comment: AHHH!!! I was not binding it right in my template. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you